# Error in creating a vector of lists

Tags: c++, list, vector

I'm trying to create a vector of lists and add elements to the lists. Below is the way I tried. But I'm getting Segmentation fault error at
'v[i].push_back(a)'. Where am I wrong in implementing it? How do I overcome it?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<list>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<list<int> > v;
    vector<list<int> >::iterator it;
    list<int>::iterator itt;
    int nv; //size of the vector
    cin>>nv;
    for(int i=0;i<nv;i++)
    {
        int a;
        cin>>a;
        while(a!=-1)
        {
            v[i].push_back(a);
            cin>>a;
        }

    }

    for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
    {
        for(itt=(*it).begin();itt!=(*it).end();itt++)
        {
            cout<<*itt<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

PS: Forgive me for the comments of this question.

Comment: On what kind of machine are running those `linux` commands?

Comment: Trying to run Google App Engine on windows is really counter productive and you will keep running into issues like this. Buy a Linux or Mac development machine. If you cannot afford that set up a VM based solution on your existing windows machine. Run Linux and GAE in the VM. Sorry I know this is not what you want to hear but comes from an expert on both windows and UNIX environments.

Comment: You don't add anything to `v` (i.e. `v` is *empty*), so of course `v[i]` where `i` is anything will not work (and probably crash).

Comment: You are missing `v.resize(nv)`

Comment: Also, you probably should have just created a *new* question, since this is, in fact, a *new* question.

Answer (score 2):

You vector is empty, since it is default constructed:

```
int main()
{
    vector<list<int> > v;
    vector<list<int> >::iterator it;
    list<int>::iterator itt;
    int nv; //size of the vector
    cin>>nv;
    // Fix the size of the vector
    v.resize(nv);
    for(int i=0;i<nv;i++)
    {
        int a;
        cin>>a;
        while(a!=-1)
        {
            v[i].push_back(a);
            cin>>a;
        }

    }

    for(it=v.begin();it!=v.end();it++)
    {
        for(itt=(*it).begin();itt!=(*it).end();itt++)
        {
            cout<<*itt<<endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```